# 2003 honda civic drove through water and wont start

Tags: troubleshooting

My husband drove through a puddle about 1 foot deep yesterday and it cut off on him and hasnt started since it is still turning over but wont fire off where should i start looking for a problem to fix. Any advice will be helpfull thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer is that he has got water on the ignition circuit - I would get WD-40 and liberally spray around the ignition leads/coils.

Worse case is he has got water in the air inlet - remove spark plugs and turn over if this is the case.

Use some easy start initially to see if there is a spark.

Comment: OP stated the engine turns over, so no water (or minimal) in the intake (not hydrolocked). Intake on an '03 Civic is pretty high (in the scheme of things) and is fairly long. Would take quite a bit of water (deep and plentiful) to get in and hydrolock the engine.